# Не выполняется запрос на добавление в таблицу

Tags: access, ms-access

...не знаю почему но при выполнении запроса на добавление записей

```
INSERT INTO Договір ( Код_страховика, Код_страхувальника, Код_страхового_випадку, Дата_початку_договору, Дата_завершення_договору, Сума_страхування )

SELECT Страховик.Код, Страхувальник.Код, Види_страхових_випадків.Код, 
CDate([Forms]![Договір_страхування_майна]![випад_ДатаУкладення]) AS Выражение1, 
CDate([Forms]![Договір_страхування_майна]![випад_ДатаЗавершення]) AS Выражение2,
CCur([Forms]![Договір_страхування_майна]![випад_СтраховаСума]) AS Выражение3
FROM Страхувальник INNER JOIN (Страховик INNER JOIN (Види_страхових_випадків INNER JOIN Договір ON Види_страхових_випадків.Код = Договір.Код_страхового_випадку) ON Страховик.Код = Договір.Код_страховика) ON Страхувальник.Код = Договір.Код_страхувальника

WHERE (((Страховик.Прізвище)=Forms!Договір_страхування_майна!випад_Страховик) AND ((Страхувальник.Прізвище)=Forms!Договір_страхування_майна!випад_Страхувальника) AND ((Види_страхових_випадків.Вид_страхування)=Forms!Договір_страхування_майна!випад_СтраховийВипадок));
```

пишет что добавляется 0 записей!!!
Не подскажите почему ????

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ваш `SELECT` без `INSERT` что-то возвращает?

Comment: @LEQADA, он должен получать данные с полей формы ...